# How to setup multiple smtp settings in meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, meteor, smtp

I want automated email in my meteor web application with two email addresses, how should i set it

following is my settings.json file

```
 {
    "smtp" :{
        "username": "XXXX@XXXXXX.com",
        "password": "XXXXXXXXXX",
        "server": "smtp.gmail.com",
        "port": 587
    },
    "email": {
        "sendMail": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't do it using the standard Meteor built in email.

You can use as many third party services such as SendGrid with any credentials you like, or you can find an npm module to provide an interface to your SMTP server(s)